# How do I paste data into a table using Confluence 5.7?

Tags: confluence

I have a pile of tabular data I need to paste onto a Confluence web page.  The usual mechanisms are NOT working properly for me.

What "usual mechanisms?"

1. Copy the data to Excel then copy / paste into Confluence.
2. Format the content using wiki markup, meaning:

   - double bars before / between / after the column header cells
   - single bars before / between / after the data cells

and paste that into the Wiki page.

The first option gets me a table, but it doesn't show the grid lines, and the sorting doesn't work.

The second option plops the markup into the page, but does nothing with it.  If I go to the first line and hit *<return>* after the last bar, it turns the line into a table with a header row (since it has double-bars). If I go to the second line and hit *<return>* after the last bar, it creates A SEPARATE TABLE with the data in it.  I can go to the first table (created from the header row), tell Confluence to add a row below, then copy the data from the second table into that second row and it will do it.  But I will need to repeat that sequence for EACH ROW OF DATA.

I've just lived with in this in the past.  When there's only a few rows, no biggie.  But I'm trying to create a table with 200+ rows.  That sequence just isn't acceptable for this amount of work.

Suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: Are you using Chrome as your browser?

Comment: Please refresh.  I edited and commented that I get the same behavior from Chrome and from FireFox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-29121), I'd assume it's a bug with the version of Confluence, at least as far as the sorting goes.

Looking through the Confluence JIRA, there appear to have been several issues with copy/pasting from Excel over the development. At least there's a workaround:

> Workaround:
>
> - Go to the editor again
> - Cut out the (unsortable) table
> - Paste it again
> - Mark the first row as Header
> - Save the page
>
> -> Now the table is sortable
>
> If that does not work, please install the The confluence source editor, then edit the page to:
>
> 1. Remove the row "             "
> 2. Replace all "td" tag to "th" tag for the first row of the table. For example, the column name "Number" will need to change from "Number" to "Number".

Comment: I tried paste -> cut -> paste -> save and that didn't help.  I tried starting with a saved one -> edit -> cut -> paste -> save but that didn't help either.Luckily, they've already installed the sourced editor.  Ended up reformatting my data into TR / TD tag pairs and pasting that into the TBODY pair and that got it all working.  Thank {deity} for gvim and macros.

Comment: See the Google Sheets answer below from @Locane.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 20):

I went a circuitous route to accomplish this:

- Made a text file with my information and tab-separated the fields
- Pasted this data in to Google Sheets
- Copied the cells from Google Sheets
- Pasted them in to the a pre-made table in Confluence

It was still faster than writing each field manually.

Comment: This work very fine! thanks you. To paste CSV data, use Google Sheets, that is clever to detect it.

Comment: Quick and easy.  Used this suggestion several times!

Comment: I was able to do it using Excel as well.

Answer (score 12):

To insert large tables with the second option you need to first hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and then paste in the table in wiki markup form.

Wrap the table in any macros required if you know the macro name and parms. This can be a serious PITA to do after a table has been created in the Confluence 5 GUI.

Click <kbd>Insert</kbd> and the resulting table will be converted to the new wiki format into the page.

Comment: I got to the point of attaching the table as a csv to the page then displaying it with a macro.

Answer (score 1):

Now, in 2023-2024, with Confluence 7.19, you can paste from Excel into a Confluence page, and it will create a Confluence table.

Answer (score 0):

My Excel has 10 K rows and some rows are with background color. To maintain the Cell background color I followed this steps

1. Saved the Excel File as HTML File
2. Open the HTML code, Copy the Complete **TABLE** (HTML CODE)
3. In Confluence page Insert HTML Macro

[image]

4. Insert your codes and see the cell color will maintain.
   [image]